# $x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}} = 2$. Why is $-\sqrt{2}$ not a solution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, radicals, power-towers

I just watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IzLADh_UCh0) by blackpenredpen where he solved this equation. Here are the steps he took (The process transitions from one line to another. He didn't explicitly use an implies or iff sign, so I'll leave it as such):

$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}} = 2$

$x^2 = 2$

$\left[ 
\begin{array}{l}
x = \sqrt{2} \\
x = -\sqrt{2} 
\end{array} 
\right.
$

At this point, he just crossed out the $-\sqrt{2}$ option.

Could someone please explain why $-\sqrt{2}$ is not a solution? Thank you!

Comment: The power tower only converges when $e^{-e}\leq x\leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Comment: Did you try seeing what the values are if you repeatedly take $-\sqrt{2}$ to the power of $-\sqrt{2}$? It doesn't give you $2$. That value is actually $-\frac{2W(\ln{\sqrt{2}})}{\ln{2}}\approx -0.76666469596...$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: If we're dealing with only real numbers, then non-integer exponents are not defined for negative numbers, so $-\sqrt2$ cannot be the base of an exponent.

Comment: bprp is also silent on what his method would yield if the RHS were replaced by 4.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Could you please explain why it is the case? I'm a first-year CS student so I'm not sure if I have the mathematical maturity to understand it. I'm asking just in case it's something within my knowledge.

Comment: @WarrenMoore Thank you for the pointer! I'm not familiar with the Lamber W function so I didn't take that approach. I'll def come back to your comment when I understand that topic.

Comment: @Polygon Thank you! I have a question. Since the tower continues to infinity and converges to 2, doesn't that mean the exponent of each $x$ in the tower is always 2, which is an integer?

Comment: @ideals_go If you've got some time, you might get a lot out of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elQVZLLiod4). I don't think it directly answers your specific question, but it gives a great intuitive analysis of the power tower, and it could help you reason about it.

Comment: @Polygon Thank you so much! It looks great!. I'm watching it right now!

Comment: @WarrenMoore  Yes, you are correct.  The Lambert W is built into my WP-34s calculator. You can't get the physical machine any more, but there is a free iPhone emulator that runs at least fifty times faster.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer**

$x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}}$ is not defined for $x < 0$.

**Explanation**

How is $x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}}$ defined? It is the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ of the sequence
\begin{align*}a_0 & = 1 \\ a_1 & = x \\ a_2 & = x^x \\ a_3 & = x^{x^x} \\
a_4 & = x^{x^{x^x}} \\
& \ldots
\end{align*}
Starting from $a_2$, these are powers whose exponent is not necessarily an integer. Such kinds of general powers are defined only if their base is positive, which for the above powers means $x > 0$.

(The general power $a^b$ is defined as $\exp(b\ln(a))$, and the expression $\ln(a)$ requires $a > 0$.)

**Comment 1**

In fact, the power $a^b$ can be defined for $a < 0$ in a meaningful way as long as $b$ is a rational number with an odd denomiator, see the comment of the user "Especially Lime" below. For example, $(-8)^{1/3} = -2$ since $(-2)^3 = -8$. However, this is still not enough for our case.

**Comment 2**

Actually, the condition $x \geq 0$ is not enough to ensure that $x^{x^{x^{x^\ldots}}}$ is well-defined. The reason is that we did not check if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ actually exists. You can find this discussion in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3552310/61691). The result is that the domain of valid numbers $x$ is
$$\frac{1}{e^e} \leq x \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}},$$
which approximates to
$$0.066 < x < 1.445.$$
Strictly speaking, this discussion is also missing in the video linked in the question: To show that $x = \sqrt{2}$ is a solution of $x^{x^{x^{x^\ldots}}} = 2$, one has to ensure that the limit exists in the case $x = \sqrt{2}$. (Disclaimer: Since the calculation in the video doesn't use any implication signs, we don't know what he claims to have actually achieved.)

**Comment 3**

The discussion of the domain of $x$ leads to the range of
$$x^{x^{x^{x^\ldots}}} = y$$
as
$$\frac{1}{e} \leq y \leq e.$$
I find it quite surprising that the range has a finite maximum.

**Comment 4**

Within the above range of $y$, we can solve the equation
$$x^{x^{x^{x^\ldots}}} = y$$
in general, in the same style as as it is done in the video linked in the question. We have
$$x^y =x^{\left(x^{x^{x^\ldots}}\right)} = x^{x^{x^{x^\ldots}}} = y$$
and therefore
$$x = y^{\frac{1}{y}}.$$
In the case $y = 2$ this reproduces the solution of the original problem as $x = 2^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I have a question. Is it necessary for $a_{n+1} = x^{a_{n}}$ to be defined as $a_{n+1} = e^{a_{n}ln(x)}$? For example, we don't rewrite $(-2)^2$ as $e^{2ln(-2)}$ because -2 < 0, but $(-2)^2$ is still a valid expression, so it seems a bit to me like we're imposing an expression that requires $x > 0$ to obtain $x > 0$.

Comment: @ideals_go For powers $a^b$ with $b$ a non-negative integer, we can use the usual definition $a^b = a \cdot a \cdot \ldots \cdot a$ ($b$ times). But for a general real number $b$, this is not possible any more, and the common definition in analysis is $a^b = \exp(b \ln (a))$.

Comment: Thank you, someone also mentioned this in a comment above and I also had a question for him/her. The tower continues to infinity and converges to 2; doesn't that mean the exponent of each $x$ in the tower is always 2, which is an integer?

Comment: @ideals_go On your other point: From a pedantic point of view, we are only allowed to write down expressions which are well-defined. So strictly speaking, the exercise should **start** with "Let $x > 0$ such that the limit $x^{x^{x^\ldots}}$ exists."

Comment: @ideals_go The symbol $x^{x^{x^\ldots}}$ is a bit misleading, look at the recursive definition of $a_{n+1}$. The sequence of exponents in $a_{n+1}$ converges to $2$, but it never equals $2$.

Comment: @ideals_go To make my last statement more concrete: $a_2 = x^x$. This expression is not well-defined for $x = -\sqrt{2}$, since the exponent is a non-integer $< 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I believe I get it now from your last two comments!

Comment: If $a<0$ you can still define the power $a^b$ provided $b$ is a rational with odd denominator. However, that doesn't really help with $x^{x^{x^\cdots}}$ as $x^x$ will be irrational for non-integer rational $x$.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Thank you for this comment. You are right, but it gets messy, and as you say, it doesn't help in this case. I will add a remark in my solution.

Comment: @ideals_go I've now added some additional info; maybe that's also interesting for you.

Comment: @azimut thank you very much for your rewrite! As to your last point, I examined the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and found that $f(x)$ increases from $0$ (at $x = 0$) to $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$ (at $x = e$) and decreases to $1$ at infinity, so that should mean as $\frac{1}{e^e} \leq y^{\frac{1}{y}} \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, $y \in [\frac{1}{e}, \infty)$. I wondered if you or I might have made a mistake. Please check again!

Comment: @ideals_go Where exactly do you think there is a mistake? I've added details to the last point, separating a comment 4.

Comment: In terms of [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), $a_n$ may be denoted ${}^nx$ or $x\uparrow\uparrow n$.

Comment: @azimut It appears I made a mistake somewhere in my reasoning. I was wondering why $1/e \leq y \leq e$. Here is what I did: $x = y^{\frac{1}{y}}$. I graphed this function, with $x$ on the vertical axis and $y$ on the horizontal axis, and found that as $x$ varies in its interval, $y$ varies in $[\frac{1}{e}, \infty)$, but yours is $[\frac{1}{e}, e]$, which should be right as the expression is known to never converge to a value larger than $e$, but I couldn't figure out what goes wrong in my reasoning.